# Trouble with expansion connector pins in spartan 3 fpga

Tags: led, fpga, switches, xilinx, spartan

I know how to turn on the fpga LEDS using push buttons and switches. I'm still having trouble figuring out how can I receive a signal from the buttons to the expansion connectors. Also, how should I modify the UCF?

Basically, how can I connect the expansion connector pins on spartan 3 fpga in order to turn on an external LED using the spartan 3 push buttons?

Comment: There aren't any "expansion connector pins" or LED-specific pins on a Spartan 3 FPGA. You're talking about a specific design. Figure out what the name of the actual board you have is.

Comment: I just want to use the 20 pins from A1 and A2 in the Spartan-3 Starter Board to toggle a led on my breadboard. I already know how to toggle the LEDS from the Spartan-3 but not an external LED.

Comment: Which Spartan 3 starter board do you have?  Would be useful to link it from your question.

Comment: I'm using Spartan3 Device: XC3S200 Package: FT256

Comment: Why is it so difficult to tell ppl what board you are using rather than wasting everyone time by saying it is a spartan 3 FPGA . If you know the name of your board, then at LEAST you should mention it here or do a simple search for your board and I bet you find 100 of examples of similar projects.

Comment: It would really help if you linked to the exact board.  I was going to edit your question to help people out but I can't because there are a number of different starter boards.

Comment: The Spartan3 does not have LEDs. That's the board it's mounted on. The Spartan3 is the chip ON the board we need to know the name of. There are a whole world of boards that have Spartan3 chips on them, and they're all very different: (https://www.google.com/search?q=spartan3+board&espv=210&es_sm=91&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=7CeRUvylHujO2AXF1YCwBg&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=986)

Comment: Even "Spartan3 Starter Board" returns a lot of variety on a Google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=spartan3+starter+board&espv=210&es_sm=91&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=cCiRUvXaIKmC2AWwpoHoAw&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=986#es_sm=91&espv=210&q=%22spartan3+starter+board%22&tbm=isch

Answer (score 1):

The following code written for the [Basys 2](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?Prod=BASYS2) board which is a Spartan 3E board BUT you will have to modify the constraints to fit your board. Just choose a IO pin and a button on your board to use.

All you have to do is pass your button value onto your IO pin like so:

```
PIO <= btn;
```

This will make so when your button is HIGH, your IO pin will be as well and vice versa for LOW.

Here is a simple demo project that uses this principle. It has been tested on the Basys 2. Just hook up your LED to the IO pin and Ground.

VHDL top module:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity buttonLED_top is
    PORT(
        PIO: out std_logic;
        btn: in std_logic
    );
end buttonLED_top;

architecture Behavioral of buttonLED_top is

begin
    -- This is where we connect the button to the LED
    -- Make sure to connect your LED to the IO pin and Ground
    PIO <= btn;

end Behavioral;
```

Constraints (ucf):

```
# Connect your LED to B2 and GND
# Pin B2
NET "PIO" LOC = "B2" | PULLDOWN;

# Push Button 0
# This will be used to activate the LED
NET "btn" LOC = "G12";
```

Comment: I have pins in A1 A2 B1 B2, these pins range from PB1-PB38 (aditionally to VDD and GND). Your module is pretty much identical to the one i had, what I think is missing is what LOC pins from the ones mentioned above should I assign my "PIO" when writing my UCF.

Comment: You should change the `LOC` for "PIO" in the contraints file to whatever pin you are going to use for the LED.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a mainstream starter board, you should be able to find a manual for it online. Said manual should have a full schematic, and pin outs for all connectors. This will let you map specific pins of the 'expansion connector' to specific pins on the FPGA. After that you only need to associate a net name to the pin location in the UCF file.